# Is the Chronicles of Darkness line suitable for play with a Story Teller and two players?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

I have a group of three players, but more often than not real-life stuff means that only two are available to play at any particular time. I've recently had my curiosity piqued by the New World of Darkness/Chronicles of Darkness lines but have read varying advice as to how well the system/style would work with mainly two, occasionally 3 players.

Is the Chronicles of Darkness system suitable for two players and a Story Teller?

Please note - valid answers to this question ***must*** draw on personal experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I play Mage The Awakening (one of the core lines in the Chronicles of Darkness) with only one player on a regular basis and while I have never maintained a long term game with exactly two I have neve let having only two of the players being available prevent a session.

The key to playing with very small groups is to tailor the challenges to the characters. This of course is good advice in any game, but with small groups that don't have a broad set of resources to draw from it becomes vital. Most of the challenges they face should be of a kind that can be directly addressed with the skills and powers possessed by the players. If and when you do give them more open ended challenges that their skills are not directly suited for, be willing to follow their lead in making the resources they look for to get around your challenge available.

This is somewhat easier with Mage where the powers given to the characters are very broad and flexible by design, but the general principle works with the entire Chronicles of Darkness.

Comment: My own, limited, experience with small CoD games led me to the *exact* same conclusion.